# pine/elm type command line email for MAPI?

Tags: outlook, mapi, curses

I wondered if anyone knew of, or had written a curses/text mode email client for MAPI

Rationale is that Outlook is pretty fat these days, and quite slow.

I'm thinking that this might be slight a strange thing to do, as google searches for anything that might do this already were largey fruitless :)

-ace

Answer (score 0):

Most outlook servers can be configured for IMAP/POP, so you could use pc-pine, or use a webmail interface to your outlook server.

http://www.washington.edu/pine/getpine/pcpine.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, but POP and IMAP are both disabled, leaving only MAPI, alas.

Comment: Actually, take a look at PC-PINE. It looks like it may also support MAPI, this release note includes: "Enhanced MAPI support for PC-Pine
"

http://www.washington.edu/pine/changes/4.30-to-4.31.html